# Pre-fill text form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a

```
<form method=post>
```

and I have a

```
<input type=text name=honnan  value="">
```

in it.

Are there any methods to pre-fill the VALUE part?

It's easy when there's only 1 thing to fill in to the VALUE, but I need several things to be pre-filled in to the VALUE.

e.g.:

ABC
DEF
GHI

So I need to give the choice to have several values in the VALUE pre-filled, just like if the browser cached the once written value to it.

A

```
<select id="old_sl" tabindex="0" name="sl">
<option SELECTED value="auto">ABC</option>
etc.
```

is not a solution because I want that the user could write custom values in the VALUES text form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JavaScript for this. Have JavaScript watch that field (e.g. use event handling to determine when the user is typing) and when the user starts to type in a value you can check to see if it matches anything of the predefined values (e.g. ABC, DEF, GHI, etc) and if it does offer them a chance to select it from a drop down that is displayed underneath that text field. Otherwise, let them continue to add their own custom value.

This is known as [autocomplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete). Popular JavaScript frameworks like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) and [Prototype/Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/docs/Ajax.Autocompleter.html) offer tools for making this easy to do.